# Warnings in Function-Like Macros in C

Tags: c, macros, warnings

If I have a function-like macro, which calls a function...
e.g.,

Function:

```
int sum(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Function-Like macro:

```
#define GET_SUM(n1, n2) sum((n0), (n2))
```

Here, in the macro parameters I have `n1`, but passing a different argument `n0`, which is not present.

I don't get any error or warning for this case? Should I pass a warning flag to the compiler to get an error/warning? I am using gcc by the way.

Have tried few warning flags like `-Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes`

Comment: No that does not exists. Macros are roughly purely syntactic, you can even write macros whose expression is not valid C expression. Errors will only appeared on expansion.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the macro so no compiler will give a warning about it.  Macros frequently do not use all the arguments and frequently use tokens not present in the argument list.

Comment: The macro also uses `sum`, which is not a parameter of the macro. Should the compiler warn you about that?

Comment: You probably should use inline functions instead of error-prone macros

Comment: It's pretty common practice that you use a macro template of some sort, but don't necessarily utilize all macro parameters. "X macros" is one such example.

Answer (score 4):

Macros are just text (token) substitutions; no syntax or semantic checks are performed as part of the expansion.  If you write

```
x = GET_SUM(i++, j++);
```

that code will expand to

```
x = sum((n0), (j++));
```

You should get a diagnostic during translation if there's no `n0` in scope or if it has the wrong type.  But as far as expansion itself is concerned, the preprocessor doesn't care.